# Python - Collapse Groups of strings

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings, e.g. `['Apple', 'Appl','Elephnt', 'Elephant']`. I need collapse this list of strings into distinct groups i.e. `['Apple', 'Elephnt']`.

My criteria for strings that should be in the same group is based on a percentage match of above 80%. i.e. Apple and Appl share an 88% match, and Elephnt and Elephant share a 93% match.

```
def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
```

The function `similar` is used to calculate the percentage match of two strings. 
How do I compute this collapse grouping using the above function?

Comment: How does this relate to `pandas`?

Comment: How do you chose the group representative, is it always the first occurrence of word from group in the initial list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to partition your initial list of strings (names) into a list of groups, each of similar strings:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
from functools import partial

def is_similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio() > 0.8

def similar_groups(names):
    remaining = set(names)
    groups = []
    while remaining:
        ref = remaining.pop()
        group = [ref] + filter(partial(is_similar, ref), remaining)
        groups.append(group)
        remaining -= set(group)
    return groups
```

For example:

```
>>> similar_groups(['Apple', 'Appl','Elephnt', 'Elephant'])
[['Elephant', 'Elephnt'], ['Appl', 'Apple']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you want. Its main problem is that it has quadratic order for large lists of non-similar strings. Given that "similar" is close to equality but not quite the same (it is not transitive, for example), I cannot see any way to reduce the order of the algorithm. For example, I do not see how to sort the items so that itertool's `groupby` function can be used.

The main idea is to add a string to the result list if it is not similar to any of the previous strings.

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

def collapse_similar(strlist):
    """Eliminate "duplicate" strings in a list, where "duplicate" means
    similar() is more than 80%.
    """
    result = []
    for s in strlist:
        if all(similar(s, v) <= 0.8 for v in result):
            result.append(s)
    return result
```

The result of `collapse_similar(['Apple', 'Appl','Elephnt', 'Elephant'])` is `['Apple', 'Elephnt']`, as desired.